# PHP session getting lost when using onclick

Tags: php, html

i redirect to a page in the same folder using onclick event to show information for different dates , but when i use onclick then it doesn't work , it only works if make a button and put everything in side a form , don't want to use buttons because it doesn't fit the style of the page. Is my code wrong or do i have to do some setting to keep the session alive.
Page A

```
<php 
//enable sessions
session_start();
$todaydate=new datetime();
$todaydate=$todaydate->format("Y-m-d");
//check if session is not set
if(!isset($_SESSION['curdate'])){
    $_SESSION['curdate']=$todaydate;
    }
// get monday's date
$daynumber=date('N',strtotime($todaydate));
$daynumber=$daynumber - 1;
$mondaydate=date('Y-m-d',strtotime($todaydate . ' - '.$daynumber.' day'));
$_SESSION['mondaydate']=$mondaydate;
$i=0;
While($i != '7'){
    $buttondate=date('Y-m-d',strtotime($mondaydate. ' + '.$i." day'));
    echo  '<span onclick="location=','B',$i,'.php'",'">',$buttondate,'</span>';
    $i++;
    }
?>
```

Page B1

```
<?php
session_start();
$choosedate=$_SESSION['mondaydate'];
$$_SESSION['curdate']=$choosedate;
include_once("a.php""):
?>
```

Comment: All those typos are just from transferrng code to here, right?

Comment: @Jeff  only have stackoverflow on my mac so had to type everything out sorry for the typo's

Comment: @Gert Why do you use `onclick=""` with `location=` and not a normal link with `<a href="...">...</a>`?

Comment: @Progman   href underlines the text don't want it to look like that

Comment: @Gert You can remove the underline with the CSS property `text-decoration`.